# Given a vector field determined by equation in polar coordinates how do I find the equivalent equation in cartesian coordinates?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, differential-geometry, smooth-manifolds, vector-fields

I have the expression of a vector field in polar coordinates, how do I find the expression in Cartesian one ?

$$X = \frac{\partial }{\partial \rho }+\frac{\partial }{\partial \theta }$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are familiar with the transformation rule for vector, it's become easy to solve. That is, if you have two different coordinate charts $\tilde{x}^i$ and $x^i$, then the basis vector transform as (with summation convention)
$$
\frac{\partial }{\partial \tilde{x}^i} = \frac{\partial x^j}{\partial \tilde{x}^i} \frac{\partial }{\partial {x}^j}
$$
In your case, the coordinates are $(\rho, \theta)$ and $(x,y)$. So for example one of them transform as
$$
\frac{\partial}{\partial \rho} = \frac{\partial x}{\partial \rho} \frac{\partial }{\partial x} + \frac{\partial y}{\partial \rho} \frac{\partial }{\partial y}
$$
And you can find the explicit expression by finding the coefficient of $\frac{\partial }{\partial x}$ and $\frac{\partial}{\partial y}$ by the relation of the two coordinates,
$$
x  = \rho \cos \theta
$$
$$
y = \rho \sin \theta 
$$